# How to look for CH340 usb drivers

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb

I need to install the CH340 usb driver on this [page](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/how-to-install-ch340-drivers/all#linux); it attaches to the Arduino machine.

The instructions were given for Windows and I am using Ubuntu Linux.
The [help](https://sparks.gogo.co.nz/ch340.html) page says the CH341 driver should already be installed.

> Drivers are almost certainly built into your Linux kernel already and it will probably just work as soon as you plug it in.  If not you can download the Linux CH340 Driver (but I’d recommend just upgrading your Linux install so that you get the  “built in” one).

`lsusb` doesn't mention anything:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0cf3:e300 Qualcomm Atheros Communications 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 5986:0701 Acer, Inc Lenovo EasyCamera
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f3:2052 Elan Microelectronics Corp. Touchscreen
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Then `lsmod | grep ch34` returns nothing.  So I'm guessing it's not installed?

Comment: What do you have in `tail -f /var/log/syslog` and `ls /dev/ttyUSB* /dev/ttyACM*` on CH340 connection?

Comment: @N0rbert I have't connected the Arduino device yet.  Perhaps that's why it's not showing?

Comment: If you didn't connect anything, did you try the [echo test](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/sparkfun-serial-basic-ch340c-hookup-guide#hardware-test)?

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a problem in 22.04 which may be related even to 20.04. When I plugged in my ch340 the kernel log `/var/log/kern.log` reported the ch340 connected as `/dev/usbTTY0` and then immediately disconnected again:

```
Jun 13 22:17:31 neptune kernel: [15500.794379] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1a86, idProduct=7523, bcdDevice= 2.64
Jun 13 22:17:31 neptune kernel: [15500.794394] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Jun 13 22:17:31 neptune kernel: [15500.794400] usb 2-1: Product: USB Serial
Jun 13 22:17:31 neptune kernel: [15500.795994] ch341 2-1:1.0: ch341-uart converter detected
Jun 13 22:17:31 neptune kernel: [15500.796670] usb 2-1: ch341-uart converter now attached to ttyUSB0
Jun 13 22:17:32 neptune kernel: [15501.346566] input: BRLTTY 6.4 Linux Screen Driver Keyboard as /devices/virtual/input/input24
Jun 13 22:17:32 neptune kernel: [15501.553569] usb 2-1: usbfs: interface 0 claimed by ch341 while 'brltty' sets config #1
Jun 13 22:17:32 neptune kernel: [15501.554415] ch341-uart ttyUSB0: ch341-uart converter now disconnected from ttyUSB0
Jun 13 22:17:32 neptune kernel: [15501.554490] ch341 2-1:1.0: device disconnected
```

For me it looks like the brltty driver is getting in the way.  I don't have any sight problems myself and don't need a brail device.  To fix I simply:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove brltty
```

And the next time I plugged in the ch340 it worked perfectly.